# Adding multiple classes when the dom element is created from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebar js for templating and i'm creating a li element as shown below.

```
var liClass="xyz" ; 
var class2 = "abc"; 
return new Handlebars.SafeString("<li class="+ liClass + ">" + "</li>" );
```

How can i added class2 along with liClass? I tried adding it to safestring but it doesn't show up in DOM properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply include multiple values separated by a space, and wrapped in quotation marks:

```
"<li class='"+ liClass + " " + class2 +"'>" + "</li>"
```